# Add email to XML file

Tags: php, xml, email, strpos

I'm NEWBIE in php. I think I've got a problem with `strpos`. I've tried everything but nothing helped.

PHP file:

```
function addMailToXML() { 

$new = $_POST['new-mail']; 
$mails = array(); 
$subject = ""; 
$body = ""; 
$data = loadConfig(); 

if(!check_email_address($_POST['new-mail'])){
echo 'Wrong address!!!';

} else {
if(strpos($data['mails'], $new) !== false) { 
echo 'Already in database!!!';

} else { 
$data['mails'][] = trim($new);
saveConfig($data['mails'], $data['subject'], $data['body']); 
echo 'Successfully registered.'; 
}
}
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item><mails>aaa@email.com,ccc@email.com,bbb@email.com</mails><subject></subject><body></body></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what the question is but you probably want to use `in_array( $new, $data['mails'] )` rather than strpos...

Comment: Thank you i just fix it with in_array. Thanks again.